# Windows Assembly Language Programming

Tags: windows, programming-languages, assembly

Can someone point to some current up to date resources on this topic? Have searched like anything but most tutos like Iczelion's are a decade old and no longer current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"No longer current" doesn't mean the information is useless.  Almost all information on Win32 assembly language still applies -- even Win95 code will still work in Windows 7, with little or no modification, as long as you don't rely on any weird hacks (and IIRC, the tutorials don't teach about such hacks).

Once you learn basic Win32 assembly (ie: Iczelion's tutorials), the rest is just new functions, structures, etc.  And that is just a trivial translation of the MSDN docs.  It all works the same way.

Answer (score 5):

Iczelion's Win32 tutorials are still current, they are just oriented for use under WinXP, they have not been updated for later OSs.

You can check out the downloads available at [masm32.com](http://masm32.com/), and the forum at [masmforum.com](http://masm32.com/). Of course you can also ask questions here - there are a lot of old time asm programmers hanging around here.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the other answers here; the content of these tutorials is still valid. However, they do not cover 64-bit assembly. If that's what you're after, I would suggest to familiarise yourself with Win32 (Iczelion's tutorials) first and then later try the same things in Win64.

The only major difference is the new [calling convention on Win64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (and that you have more/larger registers, obviously).