# Guides for Windows Assembler and an assembler compiler

Tags: assembly

I would like to get into assembler, specifically Assembler for Windows. I would like to know what options I have for the compiler, and perhaps good guides that **actually** work (on Windows and the compiler) for basic or Win32 stuff.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also take a look at my own [question about assemblers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586747/design-pattern-for-making-an-assembler).

Comment: Several guides which didn't even compile.

Comment: They are not called "guides". They are called "sample codes" or real "source codes" of other assemblers. Take a look into some available open source assemblers, such as [as source code](http://john.ccac.rwth-aachen.de:8000/as/download.html).

Comment: By the way, and `Assembler Compiler` is the `Assembler` itself.

Comment: Here is a nice-looking assember application: http://www.easycode.cat/English/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

Steve Gibson is an old hand programming for Windows in just assembler (aside from many other things including a TWiT podcast "Security Now!").
And for those wanting to start this development route, he's created [a full sample with source code](http://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm) as well as several links to Internet resources. You might want to start there.
On the page, search for the string "The Small Is Beautiful Starter Kit:" if you don't want to read the full page.

Answer (score 2):

[I am not entirely certain what it is you actually want to know, your question not being  overly specific, but I'm giving it a shot.]

There are quite a lot of useful pointers on Stackoverflow already if you check out older questions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068642/windows-assembly-language-programming), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932449/beginners-assembly-language) or (more generally) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows+assembly). Many of the old Win32 tutorials in these links (including the famous [tutorials by Iczelion](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html)) are still as valid as ever.

If your question is more about "*which assembler should I use*", I would think the stereotypical/most popular choice for Windows would be MASM (Microsoft's Macro Assembler), although other assemblers (e.g. NASM) are fine as well.

Note that a slightly less difficult/more comfortable start into Windows assembly might be not to start with a stand-alone assembler, but actually with a compiler of your favourite language that supports inline assembly, e.g. several C compilers or Delphi (which would be my personal favourite choice).